# Is there an implementation of org.apache.commons.lang.Validate for .Net?

Tags: java, .net, apache-commons

Is there an implementation of  org.apache.commons.lang.Validate for .Net ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fluent Validation](http://www.codeplex.com/FluentValidation) may meet your needs. It's not as immediate as the apache validate stuff though. Perhaps you could give us an idea of what you're trying to do, rather than just look for a direct equivalent?

Answer (score 0):

```
Trace.Assert
Debug.Assert
```

have simular functional too

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But I need validation in release version too. Thanks anyway :]